# Error: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm creating a simple login signup app. But I'm getting an error, and I don't know how to fix it, please help! Here's my code:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  CHLogbook-Application
//
//  Created by Timothy Dillan on 06/01/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 TPINC. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func createAccountTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text {
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { user, error in
                if let firebaseError = error {
                    print(firebaseError.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                self.presentLoggedInScreen()
            })
        }
    }
    @IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text {
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
                if let firebaseError = error {
                    print(firebaseError.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                self.presentLoggedInScreen()
            })
        }
    }
    func presentLoggedInScreen() {
        let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let loggedInVC:LoggedInVC = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController(withIdentifier:"LoggedInVC") as! LoggedInVC
        self.present(loggedInVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The error is in this line in the `withIdentifier` part, which, when I wanted to run it, always says "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments":

```
let loggedInVC:LoggedInVC = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController(withIdentifier:"LoggedInVC") as! LoggedInVC
```

Comment: and by the way, i'm using xcode 9.2 with swift 4 included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`instantiateInitialViewController` takes **no arguments**, it simply initializes the first view controller of the storyboard. You are looking for `instantiateViewController`.

```
let loggedInVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"LoggedInVC") as! LoggedInVC
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do not use this Code**

```
func presentLoggedInScreen() {
        let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let loggedInVC:LoggedInVC = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController(withIdentifier:"LoggedInVC") as! LoggedInVC
        self.present(loggedInVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Look Up first line. You instantiate new Main.Storyboard which takes memory. Use storyboard which already in memory.

```
  func presentLoggedInScreen() {
   let loggedInVC = storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController(withIdentifier:"LoggedInVC") as! LoggedInVC
   self.present(loggedInVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the solution, but the error is still there, could there be any other solution?

Comment: Set break point on presentLoggedInScreen(). Check that the function calls, when you perform an action.